# How to use rawQuery() to store data into a string array?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've been trying to retrieve some data from a database called **Station**  and to then store it into a database List View. When Ever I call this Activity the app stops.

**Heres the code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Station.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select * From Station", null);
    String[] station_array = new String[data_fetch.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while(data_fetch.moveToNext()){
        String uname = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
        station_array[i] = uname;
        i++;
    }
    ArrayAdapter station_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_list_view,station_array);
    ListView station_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.station_list);
    station_listView.setAdapter(station_adapter);
}
```

The App works when i comment out the line

```
Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select * From Station", null);
```

Which Leads me to believe that this line is the one causing the app to crash but I cant find anything wrong with it.

Please note that I Have created and inserted data into the  database station in a previous activity. 
Any tips would be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

PS: I am a newbie so please let me know if there is anything else of importance that i omitted!

Comment: If you have created and inserted data into the database station in a previous activity, Then why are you again open or creating It? Create Seperate class for database open or create and for everything else. You just need to create that class's object. Refer this link:: https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I thought that the variable db was how you interacted with the database my bad.

Comment: And also change your code for get all data : Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select * From Station", null);
   if (data_fetch.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        String mail=data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));     //"email"  == column name in table
                       
                    }while (data_fetch.moveToNext());
                  }

Comment: yes, that is true but, creating that every time is lil messy, so as shown in tutorial create DatabaseHandler.java. In that class, create method that returns Cursor , put your query there, and via class object access that method in Activity. and get data from Database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your Database Helper class like this

```
public static class CitrusDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        CitrusDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(TABLE_NAME_CREATE_SQL);

            // database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
```

here `TABLE_NAME_CREATE_SQL` means like this

**This Is sample**

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME_CREATE_SQL =
            "create table " + TABLE_NAME
                    + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_NAME + " text,"
                    + KEY_EMAILID + " text,"
                    + KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER + " text,"
                    + KEY_PASSWORD + " text,"
                    + KEY_USERID + " integer,"
                    + KEY_IMAGE_PATH + " text,"
                    + KEY_Notification + " integer,"
                    + KEY_DOB + " text);";
```

then you have to access your DB class like this

```
SQLiteDatabase  db =  new CitrusDatabaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data_fetch = db.rawQuery("Select * From Station", null);
```

process your cursor is like this

```
int i=0;
if (data_fetch.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String uname = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
            station_array[i] = uname;
            i++;
        } while (data_fetch.moveToNext());
    }
```

Hope, It will help You

Comment: Why did you comment out  database = this.getReadableDatabase(); ?

Comment: @Arun Mani, because, when you want to perform some fetching operations on DB, at that time you need to use this.getReadableDatabase(). Not at the time of creating table.